# Neo4j shutdown when mounting volume via Kubernetes

Tags: azure, kubernetes, neo4j, persistent-volumes

I have created a custom dockerfile for neo4j that imports necessary plugins. Next I created a deployment yaml which I am running on Kubernetes on Azure. The deployment works very well and I can reach the browser on the expected URL, which works great. However, the moment I mount a Volume, neo4j becomes unable to start with the below provided error stack. It seems that Azure is using the required directory which interferes with neo4j? However I am not sure how to fix this.

Any ideas?

Two notes:

1. Note that the directory that is mount is empty, so there is no database yet.
2. The persistent volume (claim) has been tested on a simple image like nginx, and works fine.

Find below the error stack and deployment yaml.

My demployment yaml

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: myservice
spec:
  selector:
    app: mygraph
  ports:
    - name: bolt
      protocol: TCP
      port: 7687
      targetPort: 7687
      nodePort: 30076
    - name: http
      protocol: TCP
      port: 7474
      targetPort: 7474
      nodePort: 30074
    - name: https
      protocol: TCP
      port: 7473
      targetPort: 7473
      nodePort: 30073
  type: LoadBalancer
  loadBalancerIP: 40.118.172.46
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: mygraph-deployment
  labels:
    app: mygraph
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: mygraph
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: mygraph
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: mygraph
        image: mycontainer.azurecr.io/mygraph:dev
        securityContext:
          privileged: true
        ports:
        - containerPort: 7687
        - containerPort: 7474
        - containerPort: 7473
        env:
          - name: NEO4J_dbms_jvm_additional
            value: "-Xms512m -Xmx6g"
        # When adding the below lines the deployment failes. Without it, it works great!
        volumeMounts:
        - name: neo4jdata
          mountPath: /data
      volumes:
        - name: neo4jdata
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: azurefile
```

And the corresponding error stack

```
2019-09-05 07:02:12.522+0000 INFO ======== Neo4j 3.3.9 ========

2019-09-05 07:02:12.560+0000 INFO Starting...

2019-09-05 07:02:14.122+0000 INFO Bolt enabled on 0.0.0.0:7687.

2019-09-05 07:02:14.274+0000 ERROR Failed to start Neo4j: Starting Neo4j failed: Component 'org.neo4j.server.database.LifecycleManagingDatabase@149dd36b' was successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see the attached cause exception "Unable to create directory path [/var/lib/neo4j/data/databases/graph.db] for Neo4j store.". Starting Neo4j failed: Component 'org.neo4j.server.database.LifecycleManagingDatabase@149dd36b' was successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see the attached cause exception "Unable to create directory path [/var/lib/neo4j/data/databases/graph.db] for Neo4j store.".

org.neo4j.server.ServerStartupException: Starting Neo4j failed: Component 'org.neo4j.server.database.LifecycleManagingDatabase@149dd36b' was successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see the attached cause exception "Unable to create directory path [/var/lib/neo4j/data/databases/graph.db] for Neo4j store.".

at org.neo4j.server.exception.ServerStartupErrors.translateToServerStartupError(ServerStartupErrors.java:68)

at org.neo4j.server.AbstractNeoServer.start(AbstractNeoServer.java:220)

at org.neo4j.server.ServerBootstrapper.start(ServerBootstrapper.java:111)

at org.neo4j.server.ServerBootstrapper.start(ServerBootstrapper.java:79)

at org.neo4j.server.CommunityEntryPoint.main(CommunityEntryPoint.java:32)

Caused by: org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifecycleException: Component 'org.neo4j.server.database.LifecycleManagingDatabase@149dd36b' was successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see the attached cause exception "Unable to create directory path [/var/lib/neo4j/data/databases/graph.db] for Neo4j store.".

at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:466)

at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.start(LifeSupport.java:107)

at org.neo4j.server.AbstractNeoServer.start(AbstractNeoServer.java:212)

... 3 more

Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error starting org.neo4j.kernel.impl.factory.GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory, /var/lib/neo4j/data/databases/graph.db

at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.factory.GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory.initFacade(GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory.java:211)

at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.factory.GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory.newFacade(GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory.java:126)

at org.neo4j.server.CommunityNeoServer.lambda$static$0(CommunityNeoServer.java:58)

at org.neo4j.server.database.LifecycleManagingDatabase.start(LifecycleManagingDatabase.java:88)

at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:445)

... 5 more

Caused by: org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifecycleException: Component 'org.neo4j.kernel.internal.locker.StoreLockerLifecycleAdapter@134d26af' was successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see the attached cause exception "Unable to create directory path [/var/lib/neo4j/data/databases/graph.db] for Neo4j store.".

at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:466)

at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.start(LifeSupport.java:107)

at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.factory.GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory.initFacade(GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory.java:207)

... 9 more

Caused by: org.neo4j.kernel.StoreLockException: Unable to create path for store dir: /var/lib/neo4j/data/databases/graph.db. Please ensure no other process is using this database, and that the directory is writable (required even for read-only access)

at org.neo4j.kernel.internal.locker.StoreLocker.storeLockException(StoreLocker.java:116)

at org.neo4j.kernel.internal.locker.StoreLocker.checkLock(StoreLocker.java:79)

at org.neo4j.kernel.internal.locker.GlobalStoreLocker.checkLock(GlobalStoreLocker.java:60)

at org.neo4j.kernel.internal.locker.StoreLockerLifecycleAdapter.start(StoreLockerLifecycleAdapter.java:36)

at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:445)

... 11 more

Caused by: java.io.IOException: Unable to create directory path [/var/lib/neo4j/data/databases/graph.db] for Neo4j store.

at org.neo4j.io.fs.DefaultFileSystemAbstraction.mkdirs(DefaultFileSystemAbstraction.java:124)

at org.neo4j.kernel.internal.locker.StoreLocker.checkLock(StoreLocker.java:73)

... 14 more

2019-09-05 07:02:14.317+0000 INFO Neo4j Server shutdown initiated by request
```

Comment: What accessMode did you set in the spec of the volume when creating it?

Comment: @Pablissimo accessMode for the PersistentVolume and the PersistentVolumeClaim are set at RWX. As expected, I suppose? Furthermore, I see in my Azure Files that the /data/dbms folder has been created successfully, but the /data/databases folder is not. I suppose because dbms is created during container initialization, while the /data/databases folder already exists in the docker image creation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out that it was an issue of rights of writing data to Azure. In particular in the setup of the `StorageClass` you can set additional `mountOptions`. One of those is the `uid` which should be set to 100 - the user id used for neo4j.

Example of the StorageClass yaml:

```
kind: StorageClass
apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: azurefile-neo4j
provisioner: kubernetes.io/azure-file
reclaimPolicy: Retain
mountOptions:
  - dir_mode=0755
  - file_mode=0755
  - uid=100 # Allow write access for neo4j
  - gid=1000
parameters:
  skuName: Standard_LRS
```

It is curious though that the file `/data/dbms` was written successful before, while `/data/databases` could not be written. Seems that dbms and databases are created by different users? But that would be a separate question.